# Browser Automation using Bash On Ubuntu On Windows

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, watir, watir-webdriver, bash-on-windows

We have a strong regression automation suite developed with Watir for Web Apps and Calabash for IOS and Android and so far our executions are happening on Mac OS.

We want to use RVM on Windows 10 so enabled bash feature on Windows 10 and installed RVM using Bash On Ubuntu On Windows. Using this installed RVM I would like to trigger the browsers installed on my Windows. I would like to know whether I am trying something that is possible ?

Just to check, I tried to trigger chrome browser in irb.

**I placed my chrome driver below.**

[image]

**I have set my path and find the same below**

[image]

On triggering chrome browser in irb I am getting the below error even though the path is set correct.

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:  Unable to find chromedriver.
```

[image]

I would like to know whether trying to trigger the browser installed on my windows environment through the **Bash On Ubuntu On Windows**  terminal is practically possible attempt or not ? If so, please let me know where the disconnect had happened in my setup.

Below are the versions I am installed with .

rvm 1.29.3 (latest) 
ruby-2.2.7 
watir (6.8.4)

Comment: have you tried putting the chromedriver in ruby/bin folder?

Answer (score -1):

The error you are getting generally indicates that you have installed the chromedriver.exe file into a directory that is not on your path.   Either move the file to a directory that is in the default path, or modify the path to add the directory with chromedriver.exe to the path.

Generally it's best to do that with the default path set by Windows on boot-up lest you have to have some batchfile that is run to alter the path before running IRB or a script that runs your tests.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `webdrivers` gem. It ensures you always have the latest `chromedriver.exe` in your `~/.webdrivers` directory, by downloading the newest version as necessary. It directs the Ruby code to use that driver regardless of what other chromedriver is on your system and whether it is or isn't on PATH.

Comment: Hi titusfortner , seems like webdrivers gem is working well only for chrome and IE driver. For firefox and Edge, seems like the drivers are not getting pulled and I dont see any driver for FF or Edge in .webdrivers folder. I have configured webdrivers in the projects that I have right now and this is the issue I am facing with webdrivers gem. Not sure how to resolve this, as of now I am setting the path manually by downloading the required driver.

Comment: Found an open issue for the above stated behavior for FF https://github.com/titusfortner/webdrivers/issues/3